# Disable "inlining" of imported module

Tags: typescript, tsc

To my surprise, tsc "inlines" the import of a small module. I have `l10nBundles-stub.ts`

```
const l10nBundles = new Map();
export default l10nBundles;
```

and when I `import l10nBundles from "l10nBundles"` (with an appropriate `paths` entry in `tsconfig.json`) the import statement is lost and the definition is copied into the resulting js-file.

I don't want this. This is just a compile-time dummy. The "real" `l10nBundles.js` is generated by the server at run-time and thus the `import` must be preserved and resolved (i.e. the imported module read from the server) by the browser at run-time.

I couldn't find an option to force tsc to preserve the import. Is there any? Or can I avoid the inlining by some other means?

Comment: You can try to dynamically import a module: const l10nBundles = await import('l10nBundles'). If that doesn't work you can use a 'trick' to stop tsc from evaluating an import. This has worked for me for require but it may work for you as well: const pathPadding = ''; const l10nBundles = require('l10nBundles' + pathPadding);

Comment: Thanks, but "await import" causes a lot of trouble: tsc requires module es2022, target es2017, rollup does not accept it... (didn't try to eventually fix this).

Answer (score 0):

Took me a bit more time, but then I thought, hey, if I don't provide source code but only type information during compilation, there's no source that can be inlined, right? So, using a file `l10nBundles-stub.d.ts` (note the "d") with

```
export default new Map<string,Map<string,string>>();
```

does the trick now, the `import` is left in place.